# Gulp Inject / WireDep for Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, gulp, pandoc, tex, build-system

OK, so this is a bit out there, but a little as 5 years ago a minified js file was an oddity. Today it is common and expected.

So when you look at how we compile js files into one large one, in the correct order, wiring up dependencies and all of that, how come we don't have anything like this for MS Word?

My vision is this:

40 chapter book, each chapter in its own file. Pictures in their own file, and a Table of Contents that is automatically generated on "build". A glossary that is automatically generated on "build". Templates are used to enforce conformity even though multiple authors contribute. Clickable references resolved (think Chapter 1 Heading X as being resolved).

Anyone? How would I even search for that in Google?

*EDIT:*

I have solved this problem in the past using home made software and RTF. Even in the early 2000's using XML and XSLTs. Pretty neat, but really hard to maintain. With large documents never going away, how do the big boys handle this? I can't imagine everyone has self written software to do this, or worse, letting MS Word handle this entirely.

Comment: Per your description, it seems to me you're talking about TeX.

Comment: Thanks for the tip--I looked at authorea and it is leaps and bounds in the right direction. I'm still looking to see if this is will suit me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the information about TeX I found a compelling project that seems to be exactly what I'm looking for:

[Pandoc-Seed-Project](https://github.com/Dashed/pandoc-seed-project)

It uses Gulp, [Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc), and a very similar interface for us web developers.